# Scraping iframe using Selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I want to scrape ads in websites but many of them are dynamic and they are DOM objects. For example in
[this snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASW8h.png)

I can get the iframe tag by Selenium but I cannot go any further. I think it is because of the XPATH. In this case the XPATH of the `<html>` inside the iframe is `/html` which is the same as the main page `<html>`.

This is the line of code that use:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html')))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the selenium.webdriver object is set to the default page which it has parsed. To get the iframe data you will have to switch to the given iframe.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_chrome)

# find the frame using id, title etc.
frame = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe[@title='iframe_to_get']")

# switch the webdriver object to the iframe.
driver.switch_to.frame(frame[i])
```

Always remember, **if iterating** over the iframes then to **SWITCH BACK** to the default webpage. Otherwise you won't be able to switch to other iframes in same code.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

### **Update**

Below mentioned functions are deprecated now. So i have updated the answer.

```
driver.switch_to_frame('Any frame') #deprecated
driver.switch_to_default_content() #deprecated
```

Comment: For switching to a frame as @TheoretiCAL mentioned, it's better to use 'switch_to' cause 'switch_to_frame' is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

To switch into an iframe on a page, you should use
`driver.switch_to.frame`:

```
iframeElement = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframeElement)
```

You can now use the `driver` to find elements within the iframe.

To switch back out of the iframe, use `driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Comment: `driver.switch_to_default_content()` depreciated, please use `driver.switch_to.default_content()`