# Retrieve data from HTML iframe

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to access data in an iFrame using Selenium and `BeautifulSoup4` without any success.
I want to retrieve the data present in [this dashboard](https://statbel.fgov.be/fr/commune/silly#dashboard1).

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825722/scraping-iframe-using-selenium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping iframe using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825722/scraping-iframe-using-selenium)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is a many method

for example get iframe link with selenium (if it's dynamic) and load it directly

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


src = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe").get_attribute("src")
print(src)
driver.get(src)
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "master-number"))
    )
# now you can find element in iframe
#driver.find_elements_by_....
```

more info about [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)