# How to scrape data in iframe using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, iframe, automation

I am trying to scrape data from a website
Inside a page, there is an iframe.
This is the url which I am going to scrape
https://quickfix.repairq.io/analytics/dashboard?dashboard=daily_snapshot&location=1
This is screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xqKD.png)
Here the button is in iframe and I need to click using selenium to perform the following actions
But I can't do this with selenium
Maybe there is something that i don't know but I can't find solution.

Here is the code I tried

```
try:
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

  driver.get(url)
#   log_in_link.click()
  name_input_field = driver.switch_to.active_element
  name_input_field.send_keys(username)
  password_input_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'UserLoginForm_password')))
  password_input_field.send_keys(password)
  login_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'btn-new')))
  login_button.click()

  actions = ActionChains(driver)
  reports_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Reports')))
  actions.move_to_element(reports_link).perform()
  analytics_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Analytics')))
  analytics_link.click()
  wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
  print("searched")
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, 'button')))
  open_folders_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ButtonBase__ButtonOuter-sc-1bpio6j-0.cmTxkd.IconButton-sc-n9jti8-0.iYFfNL')))
  print("open_folders_button_element:" + open_folders_button)
  open_folders_button.click()
  driver.switch_to.default_content()

except Exception as e:
  print(e)

time.sleep(5)

page_title = driver.title
print(f"The title of the page is: {page_title}")

driver.quit()
```

But I get the following

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59967/devtools/browser/d1059c6f-12c0-40be-8c1b-7cce894fac8b
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"iframe"}
  (Session info: chrome=121.0.6167.87); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6474E5E42+3538674]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF647104C02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646FB5AEB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646FFBF4E]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646FFC0CC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64703E477]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64701F0EF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64703BDE3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64701EE53]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646FEF514]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF646FF0631]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF647516CAD+3738973]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF64756C506+4089270]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF647564823+4057299]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF647235C49+720121]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64711126F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64710C304]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF64710C432]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6470FBD04]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF8997B7034+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF89B702651+33]

The title of the page is: Reports Overview / RepairQ
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping iframe using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825722/scraping-iframe-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I am sorry.
Maybe I asked a stupid question.
There were several iframes and in the first frame there wasn't element I wanted to get.
Yeah, thanks eternal_white
Thank you, all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).